# How to find the equal-weight mixture of an infinite set of probability distribution?

Tags: distributions, mean, mixture-distribution

For example, the [equal weight mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) of $p,q$ is $0.5p+0.5q$

Let $\Delta$ denote the convex hull. CASE1: The equal-weight mixture of the infinite set $\Delta(p,q)$ should be also $0.5p+0.5q$

CASE2: The equal-weight mixture of the infinite set $\Delta(p,q,r)$ should intuitively be $1/3p+1/3q+1/3r$.

However, on the same Wikipedia link, it says the uncountable mixture is defined as: $\int w(a)p(x:a)da$, where $a$ is a parameter.

I am guessing that, for the case 1, one possible parameter choice is that $p(a)=ap+(1-a)q$.

My question is, is the uncountable mixture unique? Can we calculate the uncountable mixture without specifying a parameter $a$, if the uncountable set is a closed convex compact set?